# Multithreaded program calculating prime numbers errors

Tags: c, multithreading

Here is my program that uses 4 threads to calculate all prime numbers up to 10,000,000.  I'm getting some errors and I'm not sure why, after following what my instructor has taught us I think I'm confusing myself the more I look at it.  I'm new to programming and especially multithreaded ones at that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>  // required for threads usage
#define MAX_N 100000000
#define MAX_THREADS 4

int nthreads,  // number of threads (not counting main())
    n,  // range to check for primeness
    prime[MAX_N+1],  // in the end, prime[i] = 1 if i prime, else 0
    nextbase;  // next sieve multiplier to be used
pthread_mutex_t nextbaselock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t id[MAX_THREADS];

void crossout(int k)
{  int i;
   for (i = 3; i*k <= n; i += 2)  {
      prime[i*k] = 0;
   }
}

void *worker(int tn)  // tn is the thread number (0,1,...)
{  int lim,base,
       work = 0;  // amount of work done by this thread
   lim = sqrt(n);
   do  {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&nextbaselock);
      base = nextbase;
      nextbase += 2;
      // unlock the lock
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&nextbaselock);
      if (base <= lim)  {
         // don't bother crossing out if base known composite
         if (prime[base])  {
            crossout(base);
            work++;  // log work done by this thread
         }
      }
      else return work;
   } while (1);
}

main(int argc, char **argv)
{  int nprimes,  // number of primes found
       i,work;
   n = atoi(argv[1]);
   nthreads = atoi(argv[2]);
   // mark all even numbers nonprime, and the rest "prime until
   // shown otherwise"
   for (i = 3; i <= n; i++)  {
      if (i%2 == 0) prime[i] = 0;
      else prime[i] = 1;
   }
    nextbase = 3;
   // get threads started
   for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)  {
      pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,worker,i);
   }

   // wait for all done
    for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)  {
      pthread_join(id[i],&work);
      printf("%d values of base done\n",work);
       }

   // results
    nprimes = 1;
   for (i = 3; i <= n; i++)
      if (prime[i])  {
         nprimes++;
      }
   printf("the number of primes found was %d\n",nprimes);
}
```

The errors I'm getting are as follows:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void* worker(int)’:
test.cpp:39:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
   else return work;
               ^~~~
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:57:42: error: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)(int)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
   pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,worker,i);
                                      ^
In file included from touch.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:234:12: note:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, 
const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
 extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:57:42: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
       pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,worker,i);
                                      ^
 In file included from touch.cpp:3:0:
 /usr/include/pthread.h:234:12: note:   initializing argument 4 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, 
 const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
 extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:62:31: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘void**’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int 
pthread_join(pthread_t, void**)’
       pthread_join(id[i],&work);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that a pointer is not compatible with a non-pointer value (as told by e.g. `invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘void*’`).

There are a few different solutions to this problem. One of the simpler is to use structures and arrays to pass data to the threads *and* to "return" data from the threads.

Such a structure could, for your case, look something like

```
struct thread_data
{
    int tn;
    int work;
};
```

In your `main` function you then create an array of such structures and initialize it:

```
struct thread_data work_data[nthreads];
for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
{
    work_data[i].tn = i;
    work_data[i].work = 0;
}
```

And pass pointers to this structure when you create your threads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
{
    pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, worker, &work_data[i]);
}
```

Inside the threads you need to convert the passed `void *` pointer to the correct pointer type:

```
void *worker(void *data_pointer)
{
    struct thread_data *data = (struct thread_data *) data_pointer;

    // Now instead of `tn` use `data->tn`
    // And instead of the old `work` variable, use `data->work`

    // ... Code to do the stuff...

    return NULL;  // The result is passed back through the `data` structure
}
```

Finally back in the `main` function you simply not care about the threads return value, and instead use the `work` value from the corresponding structure:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
{
    pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
    printf("%d values of base done\n", work_data[i].work);
}
```

Comment: Ok, i think i understand what your saying, anyway you can put it in the code where it needs to go?  I tried inserting the code into my code, and im not sure im placing everything in the correct spots.